# How MS Authenticator works

Tags: multi-factor, microsoft, authenticator

When using MS Authenticator on a Microsoft account, the user fills in the email address or username. After that, the user presses one of the three numbers in the MS authenticator app and is logged in. All good.

My question is what are the workings behind it?

I can find a lot of information about hashes, 2FA, TOTP authenticator apps. But nothing about the theory behind MS Authenticator. Does the app have a private key or something and only signs a certificate if the correct number is pressed? Or is the number on the screen hashed and with a salt sent to the server for authentication? Those are the two possibilities I came up with.

Comment: Do you mean this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/how-to-mfa-number-match

Comment: Thanks Schroeder! That's exactly what I meant. Well it was the direction I was looking for to study some more about it.

Comment: So, you say "3 numbers", but do you mean what the screenshots in the link say?

Answer (score 0):

MS Authenticator provides 2 modes of authentication:

**1. Notification based**

An application that uses MFA (like MS Office 365) first asks user for a password. If it is correct, at the next step the application sends a notification to the smartphone and user is requested to confirm the login request.

**2. Number matching**

When an instance of MS Authenticator needs to be bound to some account, the authentication system generates a secret initialization code. User enters this code to the MS Authenticator, via keyboard or via QR-code. When authentication is needed, the MS Authenticator takes the initialization code and the current time and generates a random number, TOTP. User enters this number to the login confirmation dialog. The authentication service generates a TOTP using the same initialization code. If the user input matches this TOTP, the authentication succeeds.

The TOTP looks random. But the algorithm is deterministic, it is based on SHA. If one uses the same initialization code on multiple devices, all of them will generate the same TOTP at the same time.

The algorithm is designed in such a way that even knowing of multiple generated TOTPs does not allow to restore the initialization code and to generate a correct TOTP.

For TOTP no communication with server is needed. MS Authenticator calculates the counter based on the current time. Within a 30 seconds interval the counter is the same. Thus, actually the counter is used for generation of TOTP. Time on the server and on the smartphone should be close to each other. Small deviations are acceptable. The server calculates counter for the current moment of time and a few past and future values. For instance, a difference of 5s will produce either the same counter value, or counter-1, or counter+1. If deviation is within allowed range, it will be accepted.

Comment: This isn't what the OP is referencing at all. It's not just TOTP. Take a look at my link above. (and this looks like a copy/paste from a wiki or chatgpt)

Comment: @schroeder: 1) This answers the question how I understand it. 2) I am using different types of MFA since about 15 years and know well how it works. I can explain well the things that I know. As you can see, some of my answers have got more than 30, some more than 50 upvotes *before* ChatGPT was available. So I don't care if my answers look similar to anything.

Comment: But then you've created a faulty logic loop. If mine doesn't answer due to "The author says despite information about hashes, 2FA, TOTP..." then neither does this since all you do is describe a bog-standard TOTP implementation. An explanation that is covered by any competent source. You have not covered *anything* about number matching, despite the heading. Again, take a look at the link I provided to the question in the comments. Take a breath.

Comment: @schroeder: I'll wait for the feedback from the author. If I misunderstood the question, I'll delete the answer. For a couple of weeks I deleted my answer that had 8 upvotes, because it was not quite good and the other answer with less upvotes was better.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/how-to-mfa-number-match

What you are seeing is just a plain TOTP process. The app just reduces the whole process down to a single digit. By having the site provide the digit for you to confirm, it does two useful things:

- it makes the user's task easier by entering a single number, not 6
- you have a, mild, level of assurance that the site you are accessing is the site that knows your TOTP secret

This process helps, in some small way, to ensure that you are not the victim of a MITM attack while providing the same convenience of Push-MFA while avoiding the "MFA fatigue" attacks.

It's a little crude in its implementation but it helps to combat the issues that MFA has been experiencing of late.

Comment: I don't understand why you are saying that this "avoids MFA fatigue"... keep in mind that number matching is for **push notifications**. It's not used in scenarios where you have to enter the 6 numbers of TOTP manually. So the users **in addition** to interacting with the notification + possibly using their fingerprint they **also** have to insert the 2 match digits. This **increases** MFA fatigue since the user has to **in addition** insert 2 digits. It does slightly increase security since it's unlikely to allow an unauthorized access since you won't know the digits to insert.

Comment: You don't answer the OP. The author says despite information about hashes, 2FA, TOTP it is still not clear how the MA Authenticator works.

Comment: @mentallurg that could simply be because it is not the normal TOTP UI and process. That's why I used the conditional at the top of the answer. MS Authenticator's Number Matching process does not look like a TOTP process.

Comment: @GACy20 you stopped reading the relevant sentence one word too soon. I said "MFA fatigue" ***attacks***. With just Push-MFA, you just get a button to push over and over again. This avoids that problem at least a little.